# Using the IF statement in PHPspreadsheet

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

I create an excel report in php using the phpspreadsheet library. But I ran into a problem: I need to use the "IF" operator in one column as in excel.

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("O{$row_number}", "=IF(A{$row_number}>10;1;0)")
```

But when I open the document, I get an error that the document is damaged. Can you tell me how to implement this correctly?

Comment: The problem is, I believe, in your unescaped quotation marks.

Comment: @Mech, This doesn't fit. In your case, the error appears even before the build

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero', This $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("N{$row_num}", "=J{$row_num}*G{$row_num}"); option works without problems. And that's exactly what IF doesn't want

Comment: Try with `... "=IF(A{$row_number}>10;1;0)"`

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero', still an error

Comment: inside if condition retrieve cell value using getcell method E.g. getCell('B8')

Answer (score 0):

Replace ";" with ",". Try

```
=IF(A{$row_number}>10,1,0).
```